# jquery get. i can't replace content of a div in ie with dynamically loaded html

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

i have a problem.
just tryin to load some html in a div...everything works fine in every browser except ie.

```
    $('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
    {
        ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
        theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
        $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ $(theDiv).replaceWith(data); });
    });
```

if i try to alert(data) in the .get callback i can read some html, but when i try to "inject" it in theDiv, i get a blank page.

thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately there was a  wich was not closed..
and ie seems to be not very flexible with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but when i try to "inject" it in theDiv, i get a blank page.

You need to cancel the default action of the link; otherwise, the link will be followed. Either add `return false` to the end of your click handler, or add [`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to it. E.g., this:

```
$('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
{
    ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
    theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
    $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ $(theDiv).replaceWith(data); });
    return false; // This both prevents the default and stops bubbling
});
```

or

```
$('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
{
    ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
    theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
    $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ $(theDiv).replaceWith(data); });
    e.preventDefault(); // This just prevents the default, doesn't stop bubbling
});
```

Separately:

The quoted code is using `ajaxLink` and `theDiv` variables from the parent scope (if they're not declared *anywhere*, they're [implicit global variables](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)). Could it be that you're changing the value of `theDiv` after the shown code runs but before the ajax call completes? That would mean when the ajax call completes, it's using the new value of `theDiv` rather than the old one.

In any case, there doesn't seem to be any reason that code should be using variables from the parent scope, I'd recommend making them local to the function:

```
$('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
{
    var ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
//  ^-- This is the new bit, the `var`
    var theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
//  ^-- And this one
    $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ $(theDiv).replaceWith(data); });
});
```

As a separate issue, are you sure you want [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) (which will *replace* the parent that has the class `post`) rather than [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (which will only replace its contents)?

There's also no reason for calling `$` on `theDiv` again; [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) already returns a jQuery object. So:

```
$('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
{
    var ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
    var theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
    $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ theDiv.replaceWith(data); });
//                                             ^-- No need for $ here
});
```

And finally: You might look at the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, which loads HTML from the server and updates the content of an element with the result.

Comment: thanks for the really detailed instructions :) i changed my code in this way:   $('a[rel*=ajax]').click(function(e)
  {
   var ajaxLink = $(this).attr('href')+"?ajax=true";
   var theDiv = $(this).parents(".post");
   $.get(ajaxLink,function(data, textStatus){ theDiv.html(data); });
   return false;
  });
but unfortunately there is the same problem. if i write theDiv.html("hello"); everything works fine! maybe the "data" in the callback is corrupted?

Comment: @Luca: *"maybe the "data" is corrupted"* Well, you said if you alert it it looks fine. I'd walk through with a debugger, double-checking things at various points.

Comment: J.Crowder , just re-checked the data in the callback and i can confirm is pure html. i also tried the load function but i get again a blank div

Answer (score 0):

can you try live instead of click and it should work fine.

sometimes in IE the DOM might not be ready

```
$(a[rel*=ajax).live('click', function() {

          });
```